# How to cast into a list from a Linq lambda expression

Tags: linq, list

If you have the following:

```
Public Class Person
{
   public int Id;
   Public String Name; 
}
```

In Program.cs,

```
String[] employeeList = new String[]{ 3, 5, 7 }
```

How do you cast the employeeList into a List of Person. I was thinking it would look something like:

```
List<Person> persons = employeeList
   .Select( e=> new { 
      Id = e.ToString(), 
      Name = e.ToString() + "hello" 
   } );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Person> persons = employeeList
// In the select part you just indicate the desired type to return
.Select(e => new Person { 
    Id = e.ToString(), 
    Name = e.ToString() + "hello" 
}).ToList(); // and cast the resulted enumerable to List<Person>
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I tried casting/ToList() before but didnt quite get the syntax right. Yours' is spot on.